# BodyPix - running toMask() and toColoredPartMask() in node.js throws an error: ImageData is not defined

Tags: node.js, tensorflow.js, masking

I am trying to get segmented person parts colored mask in TensorFlowJS bodypix model. Below code works fine before toColoredPartMask or toMask which throws an error "ImageData is not defined".

```
const tfjsnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const bodyPix = require('@tensorflow-models/body-pix');
const fs = require('fs');

setTimeout(async () => {
    maskImageWithBodyPix().then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log("Error => " + e)
    })
}, 1000)

async function maskImageWithBodyPix(image = readImage("./person.jpeg")) {
    
    console.log("loadModel ...");
    if (image == null)
        return Promise.resolve("Image Not Found...")
    const resNet = {
        architecture: 'ResNet50',
        outputStride: 16,
        quantBytes: 4
    };
    let bodyModel = await bodyPix.load(resNet)

    console.log("segmentPersonParts ...");
    let segmentedPersonParts = await bodyModel.segmentPersonParts(image, {
        flipHorizontal: false,
        internalResolution: 'full',
        segmentationThreshold: 0.5,
    })
    console.log(`ImageHeight: ${segmentedPersonParts.height} | ImageWidth: ${segmentedPersonParts.width}`)
    console.log("toMaskImageData ...")
    const maskedImageData = bodyPix.toColoredPartMask(segmentedPersonParts, false);

    console.log(`maskedImageData = ${maskedImageData}`)
    
    return Promise.resolve(true)
}

const readImage = path => {
    console.log(`readImage ...`)
    if (!fs.existsSync(path))
        return null
    const imageBuffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
    const tfimage = tfjsnode.node.decodeImage(imageBuffer);
    return tfimage;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? What does `fs.existsSync(path)` return?

Comment: I understand but I need you to run `fs.existsSync(path)` as that's the only thing that could cause the error so far as I can see.

Comment: I have edited the code, but it does the same again. And fs.existsSync returns true.

Comment: It prints the consoles as:
readImage ...
loadModel ...
segmentPersonParts ...
ImageHeight: 1280 | ImageWidth: 720
toMaskImageData ...
Error => ReferenceError: ImageData is not defined

Comment: Could you try `const maskedImageData = bodyPix.toColoredPartMask(segmentedPersonParts)` the second argument to `toColoredPartMask` is `partColors` which is not a boolean value but an array of numbers.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this too.

Comment: Even I have tried this too: 
const rainbow = [
        [110, 64, 170], [106, 72, 183], [100, 81, 196], [92, 91, 206],
        [84, 101, 214], [75, 113, 221], [66, 125, 224], [56, 138, 226],
        [48, 150, 224], [40, 163, 220], [33, 176, 214], [29, 188, 205],
        [26, 199, 194], [26, 210, 182], [28, 219, 169], [33, 227, 155],
        [41, 234, 141], [51, 240, 128], [64, 243, 116], [79, 246, 105],
        [96, 247, 97],  [115, 246, 91], [134, 245, 88], [155, 243, 88]
    ];
const maskedImageData = bodyPix.toColoredPartMask(segmentedPersonParts, rainbow)

Comment: Ah well the issue is from `toColoredPartMask` but everything seems to be fine. Could you try upgrading `tensorflow-js`?

Comment: I have these versions : 
"@tensorflow-models/body-pix": "^2.1.0",
"@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^3.4.0"
While latest @tensorflow/tfjs-node is 3.5.0

Comment: Upgraded to latest of both, but still the same issue.

Comment: I think it's the body-pix issue only on nodejs server-side, as the same logic works fine at the front-end with reactjs.

Comment: You should post an issue on the tensorlfow js github page.

Comment: Is it possible that the 2nd parameter is wrong? What is if you drop it and give only the 1st parameter: `bodyPix.toColoredPartMask(segmentedPersonParts, false);` Usually the value for the parameter is an array, so `false` might not be working.

Answer (score 1):

So this is a huge hack, but I got it working.

The problem lies in `node_modules\@tensorflow-models\body-pix\dist\output_rendering_util.js`.

If we look at this function inside:

```
function toColoredPartMask(partSegmentation, partColors) {
    if (partColors === void 0) { partColors = RAINBOW_PART_COLORS; }
    if (Array.isArray(partSegmentation) && partSegmentation.length === 0) {
        return null;
    }
    var multiPersonPartSegmentation;
    if (!Array.isArray(partSegmentation)) {
        multiPersonPartSegmentation = [partSegmentation];
    }
    else {
        multiPersonPartSegmentation = partSegmentation;
    }
    var _a = multiPersonPartSegmentation[0], width = _a.width, height = _a.height;
    var bytes = new Uint8ClampedArray(width * height * 4);
    for (var i = 0; i < height * width; ++i) {
        // invert mask.  Invert the segmentation mask.
        var j = i * 4;
        bytes[j + 0] = 255;
        bytes[j + 1] = 255;
        bytes[j + 2] = 255;
        bytes[j + 3] = 255;
        for (var k = 0; k < multiPersonPartSegmentation.length; k++) {
            var partId = multiPersonPartSegmentation[k].data[i];
            if (partId !== -1) {
                var color = partColors[partId];
                if (!color) {
                    throw new Error("No color could be found for part id " + partId);
                }
                bytes[j + 0] = color[0];
                bytes[j + 1] = color[1];
                bytes[j + 2] = color[2];
                bytes[j + 3] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
    return new ImageData(bytes, width, height);
}
```

It seemingly returns a new ImageData object. However, if we look at what ImageData actually is, we get this:

[image: imagedata]

And if we dig deeper, we get to some node.js internal typescript files and see this:

```
declare var ImageData: {
    prototype: ImageData;
    new(sw: number, sh: number, settings?: ImageDataSettings): ImageData;
    new(data: Uint8ClampedArray, sw: number, sh?: number, settings?: ImageDataSettings): ImageData;
};
```

I thought that this won't work for us, so we need to overwrite that reference somehow.

What I did was [install this package here](https://github.com/node-gfx/image-data) and added `const ImageData = require("@canvas/image-data");` line to the very top of the `node_modules\@tensorflow-models\body-pix\dist\output_rendering_util.js` file like this:

```
"use strict";
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 * =============================================================================
 */
const ImageData = require("@canvas/image-data");
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
...
```

Now when we look at the ImageData again, we get this:

[image: new imagedata]

Just by doing that and also removing the false parameter from `toColoredPartMask`-call, so it's called like this:

```
const maskedImageData = bodyPix.toColoredPartMask(segmentedPersonParts);
```

We get this result:

[image: maskedImageData]

If we were to `JSON.stringify(maskedImageData)`, we'd get a billion lines of some numbers, so I'm not going to paste that here. Anyway, I think it works now.

I think the problem lies in the node.js implementation of ImageData. We're using some kind of weird browser implementation of it. The package I installed implements an outside of browser version of ImageData and we force bodypix to use that instead with the require.

Here is my input image:

[image: input]

And here is the output:

[image: output]

**DO NOTE THAT YOU SHOULD BASICALLY NEVER EDIT ANYTHING INSIDE `node_modules`, BUT IF THIS IS JUST A PROJECT FOR FUN, I DON'T SEE WHY NOT PLAY AROUND A LITTLE**

P.S I think the first line in toColoredPartMask that checks partColors is a bit funky, so I replaced it with `if(arguments.length === 1 || !partColors) { partColors = RAINBOW_PART_COLORS; }` in my code.